# JavaFX - Unable to coerce Object to SimpleListProperty

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to establish if there's a way to load a `ListProperty`, like  `SimpleListProperty<InteractionDefinition>`, from fxml without including the `FXCollections` layer. Is there any way to have Case 1 function like Case 2?

```
public class AppMenuItem extends MenuItem {
    private SimpleListProperty<InteractionDefinition> interactions = new SimpleListProperty<>();

    public void setInteractions(ObservableList<InteractionDefintion> interactionsTmp);
}
```

Case 1

```xml
<AppMenuItem id="AppMenuItem2" menuText="View 2"  fx:id="asdDefaultView2MenuItem">
   <interactions>
        <InteractionDefinition action="actionName" button="ACTION" device="MOUSE" event="CLICK" />
        <InteractionDefinition action="actionName" button="ACTION" device="MOUSE" event="CLICK" />
        <InteractionDefinition action="actionName" button="ACTION" device="MOUSE" event="CLICK" />
   </interactions>
</AppMenuItem >
```

Case 2

```xml
<AppMenuItem id="AppMenuItem2" menuText="View 2"  fx:id="asdDefaultView2MenuItem">
    <interactions>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <InteractionDefinition action="actionName" button="ACTION" device="MOUSE" event="CLICK" />
            <InteractionDefinition action="actionName" button="ACTION" device="MOUSE" event="CLICK" />
            <InteractionDefinition action="actionName" button="ACTION" device="MOUSE" event="CLICK" />
        </FXCollections>
    </interactions>
</AppMenuItem >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer

The problem is the presence of a setter method. In the [Property Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#property_elements) section of the *Introduction to FXML* document you'll see:

> ## Property Elements
>
> Elements whose tag names begin with a lowercase letter represent object properties. A property element may represent one of the following:
>
> - A property setter
> - A read-only list property
> - A read-only map property
>
> #### Property Setters
>
> If an element represents a property setter, the contents of the element (which must be either a text node or a nested class instance element) are passed as the value to the setter for the property.
>
> ...
>
> #### Read-Only List Properties
>
> A read-only list property is a Bean property whose getter returns an instance of `java.util.List` and has no corresponding setter method. The contents of a read-only list element are automatically added to the list as they are processed.
>
> ...

When the `FXMLLoader` is processing the `<interactions>` tag it will attempt to update the corresponding property with the object(s) defined within the tag. How it updates the property is subject to the rules specified in the mentioned document—some of which is quoted above. Since you have a setter method (in the form of `setInteractions(ObservableList)`) it will try to coerce the object defined in the tag to an `ObservableList` and use the setter method; this is because the property element is determined to be a "property setter" and not a "read-only list property". Thus, *Case 1* fails because you aren't defining an `ObservableList` but rather multiple `InteractionDefinition`s.

If you want to use *Case 1* you'll need to make the `iteractions` property read-only and add a getter method. The property only needs to be read-only from the point of view of the `FXMLLoader`. In other words, as long as you don't have a setter method following the standard Java Bean conventions the `FXMLLoader` will assume the property is read-only.

Minimally, changing your code to the following will allow you to use *Case 1*:

```
public class AppMenuItem extends MenuItem {

    private SimpleListProperty<InteractionDefinition> interactions = new SimpleListProperty<>();

    public ObservableList<InteractionDefinition> getInteractions() {
        return iteractions.get();
    }

}
```

If you decide to make the property fully read-only you can use a [`ReadOnlyListWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyListWrapper.html). Or, if you don't need a full blown JavaFX property, you can just use an `ObservableList` directly.

---

## Contradictions?

There is something that seems to contradict everything just said, however. If you define a `ListView`, for example, in FXML you can also define the elements for its `items` property. This property is not a "read-only list property" because it defines a setter (since `items` is an `ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>`). Despite this, the below still works:

```xml
<ListView>
    <String fx:value="Item #1"/>
</ListView>
```

You'd expect to get the coercion error since there is a setter and it takes an `ObservableList`, not a `String`. Interestingly, if you change the FXML slightly you *will* get the error.

```xml
<ListView>
    <items>
        <String fx:value="Item #1"/>
    </items>
</ListView>
```

Now an error is thrown. So what gives? The only difference I can spot is the use of [`@DefaultProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/beans/DefaultProperty.html). It appears if a default property is specified and you **do not** explicitly use the element tag (e.g. `<items>`) in the FXML file then it will behave as a "read-only list property" (if the default property is, or contains, a `List`) and not a "property setter". Once you **do** explicitly use the element tag (e.g. `<items>`) then it behaves just as described in the first part of this answer. **I cannot find documentation explicitly describing this behavior which may mean it's a bug.** Also, note I only tried this on Java 10.0.2.

If you want to rely on this, and since `MenuItem` doesn't have a `DefaultProperty`, you could try using the following:

**Java Code:**

```java
@DefaultProperty("interactions")
public class AppMenuItem extends MenuItem {

    private final ListProperty<InteractionDefintion> interactions = new SimpleListProperty<>(this, "interactions");

    public final void setInteractions(ObservableList<InteractionDefinition> interactions) {
        this.interactions.set(interactions);
    }

    public final ObservableList<InteractionDefinition> getInteractions() {
        return interactions.get();
    }

    public final ListProperty<InteractionDefinition> interactionsProperty() {
        return interactions;
    }

}
```

**FXML file:**

```xml
<AppMenuItem id="AppMenuItem2" menuText="View 2"  fx:id="asdDefaultView2MenuItem">
    <InteractionDefinition action="actionName" button="ACTION" device="MOUSE" event="CLICK" />
    <InteractionDefinition action="actionName" button="ACTION" device="MOUSE" event="CLICK" />
    <InteractionDefinition action="actionName" button="ACTION" device="MOUSE" event="CLICK" />
</AppMenuItem >
```

Comment: Sorry Slaw! Turns out you were right on the money, and my use of a setter method was indeed giving causing my problem. 

Default items in this case aren't of much benefit to me as this is a more widespread solution to collections on our widgets, I presumed they only really added value for completely custom widgets and unique cases.